# Access to SS_cons via AlignIO

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to access the `SS_cons` line in a `stockholm` alignment that was created with infernal. I'm using `AlignIO` from `biopython 1.63`.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
alignment = list(AlignIO.parse(sys.argv[1], "stockholm") )[0]
print alignment.annotations
```

Is there a special property of the alignment object, or there is a problem with the alignment file?

[alignment file](http://pacosy.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~maze/Acoela.aln)

Comment: biopython has a bug, and AlignIO (StockholmIO ) cannot read "SS_cons" Secundary Structure Consensus in parser process .... your input is okey

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, this can not be done using Biopython (because of a bug), You'll have to do this manually, for example:

```
ss_cons = "".join([line.split()[-1] for line in open("Acoela.aln") 
                  if line.startswith("#=GC SS_cons")])

print(ss_cons)
```

you get:

```
(((((((,,<<<<............._____~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>>>>,<<<<<_______~~~~~>>>>>.,,,,<<<<<....____~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>>>.>>))))))):
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Then I will do it this way.